# SVN authentication cancelled

Tags: svn, authentication

I get the following error , both on my linux and windows boxes, when I build try to check out SVN tags from an ant build.

```
  [svn] <Checkout> started ...
  [svn] svn: authentication cancelled
  [svn] <Checkout> failed
```

How do I resolve this? **Funny thing is I can browse the repo via Tortoise SVN by entering my  credentials.**

It cannot be a "windows-has-cached-my-SVN-credtentials" issue. Since, I have cleared my SVN "auth" directory and it happens simulatnesouly on my Linux box which is oblivious to my Windows machine.

Comment: Googled this blog post which maybe helpful: http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2009/08/hudson-svn-authentication-cancelled.html

Comment: SVN is a development tool, and thus on topic here

Answer (score 28):

It depends on the version of the IDE, this problem appeared after IDEA 9 and in a first glance seems to be a bug connected to password encryption. 
[Here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56464) you have an issue reported.

They say you need to tweak .subversion/servers and set it to

```
# Password / passphrase caching parameters:
  store-passwords = yes
  store-plaintext-passwords = yes
  store-ssl-client-cert-pp = yes
  store-ssl-client-cert-pp-plaintext = yes
```

NOTE : This will store the passwords as PLAIN TEXT!

But this one does not help for version 11. 
I fixed like this for my Community 11 version :

1) Went to Settings

2) Then Version Control-> Subversion

3) Pressed Clear Auth Cache

4) Went to Changes->Repository and pressed Refresh

IDEA asked me if I would like to accept the certificate

5) Answered Accept

Then It failed to refresh with "svn: authentication cancelled" error

But in Event Log I saw

```
11:20:12 AM svn: authentication cancelled
11:21:11 AM 0 changes committed, 1 change failed to commit: Toggle Listener more 
11:23:05 AM Not Logged In to Subversion: Click to fix. Not logged In to Subversion 'Subversion Repositories'
```

6) I klicked on "Click to fix"

Then IDEA asked me to enter account and password  and I saw that the default user name that it used was my users name on my mac. After I entered the real name and password everything worked fine.

Comment: Anton, thanks, the info on Intellij 11 was very helpful.  I made some changes to users in SVN and madness ensued when I attempted to commit changes from within Intellij.  You saved me a lot of time, trying to figure this out!

Comment: Checking the event log did the trick! IDEA 13

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error (for password-less local repository).

Removing whole working copy and re-checkout helped. Credentials were asked once again for new WC guid. After that commits goes straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `.subversion` directory, used svn client for checking in modified files. Updated repository through IDE and everything started working.

Answer (score -1):

Ant might try to access the Repository in a way you don't use - like a slightly different hostname or so. Then svn asks for the credentials of this 'new' repository.

Try to get the **full** svn command line that ant executes and run it yourself. I am no ant expert, can't help you there.